# How do I return a string in C?

Tags: c, string, function, return, cs50

So I was trying to do a problem set on the Harvard CS50 course. I was able to create the program but wanted to make it cleaner in terms of design. I decided to use a function.

The goal was to create a program that takes the height value that is between 1 and 8. If the height was 1, then the output would be `# #`. If the height increased, then the output would include 2 more players with 1 extra `#` to the left and right.

When I tried to return a value and create a function with a return type of `string`, I kept getting errors.

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>

char *mario();

int main(void){

    printf("%c", mario());

}


char *mario(){

    int stop = 0;

    while(stop == 0){

        unsigned int height = get_int("Height: ");
        char *result = " ";

        if(height == 1){

            printf("\n# #\n");
            stop = 1;

        }else if(height == 2){

            result = "\n # #\n## ##\n";
            stop = 1;

        }else if(height == 3){

            result = "\n  # #\n ## ##\n### ###\n";
            stop = 1;

        }else if(height == 4){

            result = "\n   # #\n  ## ##\n ### ###\n#### ####\n";
            stop = 1;

        }else if(height == 5){

            result = "\n    # #\n   ## ##\n  ### ###\n #### ####\n##### #####\n";
            stop = 1;

        }else if(height == 6){

            result = "\n     # #\n    ## ##\n   ### ###\n  #### ####\n ##### #####\n###### ######\n";
            stop = 1;

        }else if(height == 7){

            result = "\n      # #\n     ## ##\n    ### ###\n   #### ####\n  ##### #####\n ###### ######\n####### #######\n";
            stop = 1;

        }else if(height == 8){

            result = "\n       # #\n      ## ##\n     ### ###\n    #### ####\n   ##### #####\n  ###### ######\n ####### #######\n######## ########\n";
            stop = 1;
        }

    }

    return result;
}
```

Error:

```
mario.c:33:7: error: conflicting types for 'mario'
char *mario(){
      ^
mario.c:5:5: note: previous declaration is here
int mario(void);
    ^
mario.c:88:12: error: use of undeclared identifier 'result'
    return result;
           ^
2 errors generated.
<builtin>: recipe for target 'mario' failed
make: *** [mario] Error 1
```

How can I fix this?

I am using CS50's library as seen and the IDE.

Comment: `char *mario()` and `int mario(void)` together with `error: conflicting types for 'mario'
char *mario(){
      ^
mario.c:5:5: note: previous declaration is here
int mario(void);` isn't clear?

Comment: I know, I fixed that but I still get the error. Check the edited code.

Comment: Are you sure that you saved the file and/or are compiling the right file? There is no way you can still have that exact error. Unless there is more your are not showing us.

Comment: I am using `make mario` in the terminal as the file name is mario.c.

Comment: Does your Makefile use the correct `mario.c` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Change `int mario(void);` to `char *mario(void);`
2. Change `printf("%c", mario());` to `printf("%s", mario());`
3. Move `char *result = " ";` to the start of the `mario()` function so it is in-scope for `return`.

Comment: I still get this error:


mario.c:88:12: error: use of undeclared identifier 'result'
    return result;
           ^
1 error generated.
<builtin>: recipe for target 'mario' failed
make: *** [mario] Error 1

Comment: @KhosrawAzizi did you review answer part 3?

Comment: Thanks, it worked, but can you explain why that happened? I though variables in C work everywhere once declared.

Comment: In "C", variable scope is within the closest enclosing set of curly braces `{` `}`, even if those are part of a `while` loop.  More precisely, the scope is from the point of the variable definition, to the closest enclosing `}`.

Comment: Nitpick: The returned type should be a pointer to const char.

Comment: @4386427 agreed that using `const` is the preferred practice, although `char *` is syntactically correct for 'C' and in this case OP's code makes no attempts to modify the string.  Many surprises await those who dare venture into the 'C' minefield.  :)

Comment: @rtx13 True - in this case OP doesn't modify the string. But who knows how OP will modify the program in the future. Doing it correctly from the start costs little and reduces the "C minefield" expirence.